# Android Studio - What are possible options to overlay two images and make only the right or left half of each image visible?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I am trying to have two images overlayed in two imageViews and when i start a swiping gesture the upper image is cropped vertically at the starting point of my touch gesture and the cropping line follows my gesture on screen to the left or right. When I move my finger to the right the cropping line should follow it and reveal more of the upper image for example, until I lift my finger from the screen. The crop should stay there then.

The goal ist to be able to compare two images with a swiping gesture.
I hope what I am trying to achieve is halfway understandable and I would be happy about any kind of input regarding that topic ;)
Thank you in advance